# part of a regular expression not matching in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

i posted this in another question but i think its seperate and so i made another.

the replace method has regular expressions in it. the expressions all match correctly and replace.  This `replace(/\(he\/\she\)/g,"he")` and this `replace(/\(he\/\she\)/g,"she")`

dont replace... i dont know why.
here is the code.

```
function replaceGender(name, gender, comment) {

  if(gender == "m")
  {
    comment = comment.replace(/\(name\)/g, name).replace(/\(He\/She\)/g,"He").replace(/\(His\/\Her\)/g,"His").replace(/\(his\/\her\)/g,"his").replace(/\(he\/\she\)/g,"he").replace(/\(him\/\her\)/g,"him");
  }
  else if(gender == "f")
  {   
    comment = comment.replace(/\(name\)/g, name).replace(/\(He\/She\)/g,"She").replace(/\(His\/\Her\)/g,"Her").replace(/\(his\/\her\)/g,"her").replace(/\(he\/\she\)/g,"she").replace(/\(him\/\her\)/g,"her");
  }

  return comment;
};
```

here is some input
"She reads clearly and with confidence. Her writing skills are very good for her level. I'm sure that if Jenna continues to work hard (he/she) will become a strong English speaker in the future."

everything els replaced fine.. just (he/she)

Comment: Why are you escaping the `s` in `/\(he\/\she\)/`? Shouldn't that be `/\(he\/she\)/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/\(he\/\she\)/g` would replace "(he/ he)" (because `\s` matches any whitespace).

It should be `/\(he\/she\)/g` if you want to replace "(he/she)".

Comment: thanks so much!! this works... but i dont understand why the others replaced ok if they are also incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This will work..

```
function replaceGender(name, gender, comment) {

  if(gender == "m")
  {
    comment = comment.replace(/\(name\)/g, name).replace(/\(He\/She\)/g,"He").replace(/\(His\/Her\)/g,"His").replace(/\(his\/her\)/g,"his").replace(/\(he\/she\)/g,"he").replace(/\(him\/her\)/g,"him");
  }
  else if(gender == "f")
  {   
    comment = comment.replace(/\(name\)/g, name).replace(/\(He\/She\)/g,"She").replace(/\(His\/Her\)/g,"Her").replace(/\(his\/her\)/g,"her").replace(/\(he\/she\)/g,"she").replace(/\(him\/her\)/g,"her");
  }
  return comment;
};
```